# Remove n characters from a start of a string

Tags: python, string

I want to remove the first characters from a string. Is there a function that works like this?

```
>>> a = "BarackObama"
>>> print myfunction(4,a)
ckObama
>>> b = "The world is mine"
>>> print myfunction(6,b)
rld is mine
```

Comment: I have never written a word of Python and yet I was able to find the answer to this. I suggest you search for "String Manipulation in Python" in Google. Here's one link: http://www.astro.ufl.edu/~warner/prog/python.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove left part of a string in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599953/how-to-remove-left-part-of-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function could be:

```
def cutit(s,n):    
   return s[n:]
```

and then you call it like this:

```
name = "MyFullName"

print cutit(name, 2)   # prints "FullName"
```

Answer (score 18):

Yes, just use slices:

```
 >> a = "BarackObama"
 >> a[4:]
 'ckObama'
```

Documentation is here http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: Short, succinct and clear. With a reference directly to String section. Mine is just a poor rehash. I learned some Python to answer this question... and I shall now remove my answer. Must cut the clutter!

Answer (score 8):

Use slicing.

```
>>> a = "BarackObama"
>>> a[4:]
'ckObama'
>>> b = "The world is mine"
>>> b[6:10]
'rld '
>>> b[:9]
'The world'
>>> b[:3]
'The'
>>>b[:-3]
'The world is m'
```

You can read about this and most other language features in the official tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tut/

Answer (score 4):

```
a = 'BarackObama'
a[4:]  # ckObama
b = 'The world is mine'
b[6:]  # rld is mine
```