# How to remove a substring from a string using PHP?

Tags: php, string

Given the following string

```
http://thedude.com/05/simons-cat-and-frog-100x100.jpg
```

I would like to use `substr` or `trim` (or whatever you find more appropriate) to return this

```
http://thedude.com/05/simons-cat-and-frog.jpg
```

that is, to remove the `-100x100`. All images I need will have that tagged to the end of the filename, immediately before the extension.

There appears to be responses for this on SO re Ruby and Python but not PHP/specific to my needs.

[How to remove the left part of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599953/how-to-remove-left-part-of-a-string-in-python)

[Remove n characters from a start of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782318/remove-substring-from-a-string)

[Remove substring from the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367164/remove-substring-from-the-string)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you plan on hardcoding the value of the substring? Or do you want to match any -WIDTHxHEIGHT.ext form of substring?

Comment: Would you mind linking to the Ruby and Python versions you found? The techniques used there are probably relevant.

Comment: @minitech - added a few links in OP

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to match any width/height values:

```
  $path = "http://thedude.com/05/simons-cat-and-frog-100x100.jpg";

  // http://thedude.com/05/simons-cat-and-frog.jpg
  echo preg_replace( "/-\d+x\d+/", "", $path );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/cnKum1kd

The pattern used is pretty basic:

```
/     Denotes the start of the pattern
-     Literal - character
\d+   A digit, 1 or more times
x     Literal x character
\d+   A digit, 1 or more times
/     Denotes the end of the pattern
```

Comment: after all is said and done, this may be the versatile solution, in case these thumbnails end up changing in size

Answer (score 23):

```
$url = "http://thedude.com/05/simons-cat-and-frog-100x100.jpg";
$new_url = str_replace("-100x100","",$url);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$url = str_replace("-100x100.jpg", '.jpg', $url);
```

Use `-100x100.jpg` for bullet-proof solution.

Comment: But he needs the extension to remain, so add '.jpg' as the replacement value

Answer (score 3):

If `-100x100` are the only characters you're trying to remove from all of your strings, why not use `str_replace`?

```
$url = "http://thedude.com/05/simons-cat-and-frog-100x100.jpg";
str_replace("-100x100", "", $url);
```