# How do I replace a line of a file using python with wild card

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7-x64

I'm new to python and am using version 2.7

I would like to replace the `string` inside a file using a `wild card` that fills out the rest of that line. Here is what I have so far...

This will work and change the file string to `second string`:

```
if line == 'This = first string':
    line = 'This = second string'
```

This will not work and the file string will remain as `first string`:

```
if line == 'This = *':
    line = 'This = second string'
```

Full Script:

```
import sys
import shutil
import os
import re

#Assigns tf as a tmp file with the module for appending and writing, and creating the file if it does not exist.
tf = open('tmp', 'a+')

#Assigns f as test.txt
with open('test1.txt') as f:
#Reads the line in the test1.txt file
    for line in f.readlines():
#Checks for the line condition
        if line == 'This = *':
#Sets the new line condition
            line = 'This = second string'
#Replaces the line withe the new build path
        tf.write(line)
#Closes the test2.txt file
f.close()
tf.close()
#Copies the changes from the tmp file and replaces them into the test2.txt
shutil.copy('tmp', 'test2.txt')
#Removies the tmp file from the computer
os.remove('tmp')
```

Latest Code for **J.F. Sebastian**

test2.txt contents:

```
blah
This = first string
```

testing2.py contents:

```
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

prefix = "This = "
path = 'test2.txt'  
dirpath = os.path.dirname(path)
with open(path) as input_file:
    with open(path+".tmp", mode="w") as tmp_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if line.startswith(prefix):
                line = prefix + "second string\n"
            tmp_file.write(line)
        tmp_file.delete = False
os.remove(path)
os.rename(tmp_file.name, path)
```

Error Message:

```
C:\Users\james>testing2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\james\testing2.py", line 13, in <module>
    tmp_file.delete = False
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried to fix the `AttributeError`? What do you expect `tmp_file.delete = False` line to do? Why is it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer...

test1.txt before Nightly.py executed:

```
blah
blah
This is a first string
blah
blah
```

BTW tabs make a difference in the code with notepad++

```
import sys
import os
import re
import shutil

tf = open('tmp', 'a+')

with open('test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        build = re.sub ('This is.*','This is a second string',line)
        tf.write(build)
tf.close()
f.close()
shutil.copy('tmp', 'test1.txt')
os.remove('tmp')
```

test1.txt after Nightly.py executed:

```
blah
blah
This is a second string
blah
blah
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace lines that start with the prefix:

```
prefix = "This = "
if line.startswith(prefix):
    line = prefix + "second string"
```

If the file is a config file with `key = value` lines then you could also replace the value using [`line.partition()` method, `ConfigParser` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600195/4279), or regular expressions (in more complex cases):

```
import re
# ...
line = re.sub(r"^This\s*=.*$", "This = second string", line)
```

To replace lines in a file; you could use [`fileinput` module or just write to a temporary file (`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`) and rename it at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

prefix = "This = "
path = 'test1.txt'  
dirpath = os.path.dirname(path)
with open(path) as input_file:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", dir=dirpath) as tmp_file:
        for line in input_file:
            if line.startswith(prefix):
                line = prefix + "second string\n"
            tmp_file.write(line)
        tmp_file.delete = False
os.remove(path)
os.rename(tmp_file.name, path)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `expected an indented block` for the `prefix` or `line`. I updated the full script so maybe you could get a clearer picture

Comment: @FiddleFreak: Post the code that raises the error with the full traceback. Check that you don't mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: Posted it, awaiting response...

Comment: @FiddleFreak: I've added complete code example.

Comment: still not working. I got an error for the last line `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: @FiddleFreak: I've updated the code to remove the file before the `rename` call which fails on Windows if a destination file exists already. Though the error message would've been different. Check that `tmp_file.delete` line is indented properly.

Comment: Same error, only this time it is deleting the file.

Comment: @FiddleFreak: Post the code that raises the error with the full traceback. Make sure the indentation is correct.

Comment: Updated for review...

Comment: @FiddleFreak: the code should work. Try `with open(path+".tmp", "w") as tmp_file:` instead of `NamedTemporaryFile`.

Comment: I updated the error for you...

Comment: I just got an idea. Would there be a way to do this: if line contains prefix, set linenumber. linenumber.remove (this will remove everything in that line). linenumber.write 'This = second string'