# Remove a prefix from a string

Tags: python

I am trying to do the following, in a clear pythonic way:

```
def remove_prefix(str, prefix):
    return str.lstrip(prefix)

print(remove_prefix('template.extensions', 'template.'))
```

This gives:

```
xtensions
```

Which is not what I was expecting (`extensions`). Obviously (stupid me), because I have used [lstrip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip) wrongly: lstrip will remove all characters which appear in the passed `chars` string, not considering that string as a real string, but as "a set of characters to remove from the beginning of the string".

Is there a standard way to remove a substring from the beginning of a string?

Comment: On Python 3.9+, use [`str.removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix)

Comment: Useful [features for `removeprefix()` and `removesuffix()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599953/how-to-remove-the-left-part-of-a-string/64400605#64400605) in the newly released Python 3.9.

Comment: One-liner from @martineau's answer: `remove_prefix = lambda text, prefix: text[len(prefix):] if text.startswith(prefix) else text`

Answer (score 431, accepted):

For Python 3.9+:

```py
text.removeprefix(prefix)
```

For older versions, the following provides the same behavior:

```py
def remove_prefix(text, prefix):
    if text.startswith(prefix):
        return text[len(prefix):]
    return text
```

Comment: Starting in `Python 3.9`, you can use [`removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=removeprefix#str.removeprefix). For an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432546/1518225).

Comment: Cool! Note: the behavior of the new function is exactly as in this answer (returning the string unchanged if it does not start with `prefix`)

Comment: And the `endswith()` parallel is `removesuffix()`

Comment: a side note is that [pep-0616](https://peps.python.org/pep-0616/) that added the method to 3.9, includes example polyfill code and their behavior is to return copy of the string when no match is made: `return self[:]`

Comment: @glen this does not guarantee copying (which would be useless anyway). `x = 'a b'; assert x is x[:]` works in CPython3.11

Answer (score 74):

Short and sweet:

```
def remove_prefix(text, prefix):
    return text[text.startswith(prefix) and len(prefix):]
```

Comment: @jamylak it's like the "ternary" and-or, but correct :) ... +1, although I think it's a bit too clever for real code. And you can't decide you want it to raise an exception otherwise.

Comment: @Oliver: I disagree…it's just idiomatic Python coding for those that know how the language works.

Comment: Well you definitely have to think a lot longer when reviewing code like this in comparison to the accepted answer, even if you work with Python more often.

Comment: Downvoted. This is the kind of unnecessary clever stuff that makes reading even MY OWN CODE more difficult.

Comment: @MrR: Python also has another, frequently underused, feature: comments.

Comment: @martineau So you're proposing writing something cleverly, then comment on it to understand it better, rather than just writing in a simpler straighforward-to-understand-without-comment fashion. No, thanks.

Comment: @MrR: I only suggested doing that for those who are unable to recognize what it's doing (likely because they don't understand the language or its idioms well). Another nice feature of comments is they don't slow down code execution.

Comment: Comments risk becoming detached from the code they refer to, so are a far cry from a panacea for code clarification. I much prefer code that's self-commenting.

Comment: I think it is not only clever but also readable: One should know that boolean are underlying integers. If you want to make clearer that we are using the boolean of "startswith" for calculation I suggest to replace the `and` with a `*`. This might - in fact - be a bit slower, but gives a - very strong - indicator to what we are doing here.

Comment: @Make42: Good point about using `*` which doesn't require understanding how the `and` operator works — even though `*` itself has a number of different meanings in Python, depending on context. My personal goal is to write code that's both efficient and understandable by anyone who knows the language at least as well as I do. `;¬)`

Comment: "as well as I do" - however consider that you yourself do not know the a specific aspect of the language continuously well. Meaning: You learn knew stuff and forgot other stuff. Also: You do not code for the machine, you do not code for yourself, you code for other programmers. (Even if that other programmer is you, but at a different time.) So, in a way the remarks are somewhat valid. Although I feel that your code is (barely) not too clever.

Comment: @Make42: I generally don't write code for me or anyone else who even learned the basics of the language yet such as how the boolean operators work. Yes, there was a short period where I might not have known it well, but again, that's not a target audience I any concerns about at all. Anyway, as I said in my very first comment far above, I don't consider the code "too" (or even "very") clever either—so we're basically in agreement.

Answer (score 54):

What about this (a bit late):

```
def remove_prefix(s, prefix):
    return s[len(prefix):] if s.startswith(prefix) else s
```

Comment: +1 Concise. But can you make it Raise something in the error case, and still fit it in 2 lines x 80 columns?

Comment: @personal_cloud: `return s[s[:len(prefix)].index(prefix) + len(prefix):]`

Answer (score 17):

regex solution (The best way is the solution by @Elazar this is just for fun)

```
import re
def remove_prefix(text, prefix):
    return re.sub(r'^{0}'.format(re.escape(prefix)), '', text)

>>> print remove_prefix('template.extensions', 'template.')
extensions
```

Answer (score 16):

I think you can use methods of the `str` type to do this. There's no need for regular expressions:

```
def remove_prefix(text, prefix):
    if text.startswith(prefix): # only modify the text if it starts with the prefix
         text = text.replace(prefix, "", 1) # remove one instance of prefix
    return text
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def remove_prefix(s, prefix):
    if s.startswith(prefix):
        return s[len(prefix):]
    else:
        return s
```