# Remove a set of prefix characters from string in python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all the prefix "@" from the string "@@@@b@@"
Expected output is "b@@" (not all the '@' but only prefix)
If there is no prefix "@", it should return the original string itself
This is the code, I am trying : (I am using python 2.X)

```
mylist = []




def remove(S):
    mylist.append(S)
    j=0
    for i in range(len(S)):
        if mylist[0][j]=='@':
            S = S[:j] + S[j + 1:]
            j+=1
            return S


        else:
            return S
            break




a = remove("@@@@b@@")

print a
```

Comment: What isn't working? What output are you getting?

Comment: Simply do `a.lstrip('@')`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip)

> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. The *chars* argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.

```
>>> "@@@@b@@".lstrip("@")
'b@@'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python 3.9**
There are two new string methods, removesuffix() and removeprefix()

```
"HelloWorld".removesuffix("World")
```

> Output: "Hello"

```
"HelloWorld".removeprefix("Hello")
```

> Output: "World"

**Before Python 3.9**

1. Using lstrip() (See Christians answer)
   Be careful using lstrip and rstrip. If you are trying just to remove the first few letters. lstrip() and rstrip() will keep removing letters until it reaches an unrecognizable one.

   ```
     a = "@@@b@@"  
     print(a.lstrip('@@@b'))
   ```

> Output:
> Above output is a empty string, lstrip strips off everything!

```
a = "@@@b@@c"
print(a.lstrip('@@@b'))
```

> Output: c

2. Use a regular expression

> ```
>   import re
>   url = 'abcdc.com'
>   url = re.sub('\.com$', '', url)
> ```

Comment: `a.lstrip('@@@b')` is misleading because`lstrip` argument is a character set, not a string.  Using lstrip may be convenient when the prefix is stored in a variable. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/16891427/2325279 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16891418/2325279 are both easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove(S): return S[4:] if S.startswith('@@@@') else S
>>> remove('@@@@b@@')
'b@@'
>>> remove('@@@b@@')
'@@@b@@'
```