# python program to convert the hex values to ASCII strings

Tags: python

when I enter a command in command line, I got the output like below. wanted to write a python program which will take the first line's only hex values as input (`31 2e 30 38 2e 32 30 32 31 30 38 32 35 00 00 00`) and convert to ASCII string.

```
$> set system cmd -i 33 -c raw 0x38 0x0b 0x06 -- command 

    Ipmi Response: 31 2e 30 38 2e 32 30 32 31 30 38 32 35 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   Completion Code: Success
```

Tried this:

```
hex_str = "31 2e 30 38 2e 32 30 32 31 30 38 32 35 00 00 00"
string = ''.join(chr(int(i, 16)) for i in hex_str.split())
```

but not sure how to remove the `"Ipmi response: "` part from the string.

Comment: Use a slice.  `hex_str = main_str[len('Ipmi Response: '):]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a prefix from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891340/remove-a-prefix-from-a-string)

Comment: its not about remove the prefix, but python program to take the command output's first line as input and convert the hex values to ascii string