# Remove prefix from python list objects and single quotes

Tags: python, string, list

Here is my list:

`[Volume:vol-b81a2cb0, Volume:vol-ab2b1ba3, Volume:vol-fc2c1cf4]`

I want it to look like this:

```
['vol-b81a2cb0', 'vol-ab2b1ba3', 'vol-fc2c1cf4']
```

So the following should be done:

1. The `Volume:` prefix must be removed from the list elements.
2. The new elements must be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/599962/2286508

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
strList = map( str, objList)
strList = map( lambda x: x.replace( 'Volume:', ''), strList)
```

Comment: The first line turns the list of objects to a list of strings representing those objects. Now, how effective this is depends on how the object's class is defined, namely, what the .str (or .display I think) method does. 

The second line will indeed only work on list of strings.

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce @Marek code to one line:

```py
strList = list(map(lambda x: str(x).replace('Volume:', ''), strList))
```

or just use *list comprehension*:

```py
new_list = [str(i).replace( 'Volume:', '') for i in your_list]
```

---

Since **Python 3.9** you can use `removeprefix()` function what will simplify your code even more:

```py
new_list = [str(i).removeprefix('Volume:') for i in your_list]
```

More info about `removeprefix()`: [PEP 616](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/)