# str.lstrip() unexpected behaviour

Tags: python

I am working on a scrapy project and was trying to parse my config

The string is `attr_title` I have to strip 'attr_' and get `title`. I used lstrip('attr_'), but getting unexpected results. I know `lstrip` works out combinations and removes them, but having hard time understanding it.

```
In [17]: "attr.title".lstrip('attr.')
Out[17]: 'itle'
```

PS: I know there are multiple solutions for extracting string I am interested in understanding this.

Comment: related: [Python - how to remove the left part of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/599953/4279)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lstrip` `iterates` over the result string until there is no more combination that matches the left most set of characters

A little illustration is below.

```
In [1]: "attr.title".lstrip('attr.')
Out[1]: 'itle'  # Flow --> "attr." --> "t" --> Next char is 'i' which does not match any combination hence, iteration stops & end result ('itle') is returned

In [2]: "attr.tritle".lstrip('attr.')
Out[2]: 'itle' # "attr." --> "t" --> "r" --> Next char is 'i' which does not match any combination hence, iteration stops & end result ('itle') is returned

In [5]: "attr.itratitle".lstrip('attr.')
Out[5]: 'itratitle' # "attr." --> Next char is 'i' which does not match any combination hence, iteration stops & end result ('itratitle') is returned
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, and for the example illustrations. That helped understand even better.

Comment: There is nothing recursive about this.

Comment: Recursively must be taken with grammatical context... As OP was having hard time understanding I explained it further.

Comment: As Tim say, the `strip` methods do **not** operate recursively - they use a simple `while` loop. Your explanation would be more accurate if you said "`lstrip` operates iteratively on the input string". See [the source code](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup) for `do_argstrip()` (starting at line #1882) for details.

Answer (score 5):

```
"attr.title".lstrip('attr.')
```

means "remove every `a`, `t`, `t`, `r`, `.` from the left of the given string until no such character occurs.

Then it takes the given string and removes the `a`, the two `t`s, the `r`, the `.` and the `t`, as they all are contained in the given pattern.

At the `i` it stops as it is not contained in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, ahhh, now I get it.

Comment: @geethaar: unfortunately, unlike `.startswith()` method `.lstrip()` does not accept a `tuple()` argument (to strip whole strings instead of individual characters)