# python 3 remove leading substring from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

Suppose I have a filename `./file` and I want to remove the leading `./` (if it starts with `./`). What would be the best python way to do this? My take at this is:

```
if filename.startswith("./"):
  # remove leading ./
  filename = filename[2:]
```

Isn't there a more elegant way?

PS: it should remove the leading part only if it matches exactly, think of the following filenames:

```
./filename
.configfile
../file
./.configfile
```

Comment: `new_list = [element.replace("./", "") for element in old_list]`

Comment: See [How to remove the left part of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599953/how-to-remove-the-left-part-of-a-string)

Comment: @OlvinRoght That will replace a part of "../" also...

Comment: @Itay, you can add `if element.startswith(".\")` if it's needed. It's just quick comment, not an nswer, feel the deffierence

Comment: You can simply use `regex`: `re.sub(r'^./', '', file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filenames = ['.configfile', './file1', './dir/file2']
filenames = [fn[2:] if fn.startswith("./") else fn for fn in filenames]
```

borrowing from your idea but doing it in one line

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference would be the solution by @user1443098
But for completnes - using re

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^\./')
files = ['./filename', '.configfile', '../file']
new_files = [re.sub(pattern, '', fname) for fname in files]
print(new_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is the ways it's usually done. Of course, you can always move it into a function:

```
def remove_prefix(s, prefix):
    if s.startswith(prefix):
        s = s[len(prefix):]
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing a helper function:

```
def strip_prefix(s, prefix):
  if s.startswith(prefix):
    return s[len(prefix):]
  else:
    return s

print(strip_prefix('./filename', './'))
print(strip_prefix('.configfile', './'))
print(strip_prefix('../file', './'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using python3, the best way to deal with paths is trough the `pathlib` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

if you only want the filename

```
from pathlib import Path
paths = ["./filename", ".configfile", "../file"]
only_filenames = [Path(f).name for f in paths]
```

Comment: This is not what the question asks, only exact matches to `./` should be removed, something like `../` should stay the same. Nowhere is stated that only the filename is wanted

Answer (score -3):

```
if filename.startswith("./"):
    filename.lstrip("./")
```

Comment: that would mess up `./.configfile`

Comment: Additionally, this would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.